# Vim trailing characters search

Tags: vim

I know I have to escape regex special characters in a search and replace in vim, but I can't see what I'm missing here.  I do this:

```
:%s/RAILS_ROOT/Rails\.root\.to_s/gj
```

and I get the "trailing characters" error in Vim.

I have also tried escaping the _ the same way, just in case, same result.  Any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: just to make sure: did you escape both the `_` using \ _ ?

Comment: Yes, I said that in my original post...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try removing the j at the end. `:%s/RAILS_ROOT/Rails\.root\.to_s/g` j is not a valid flag for `:substitute` as far as I can tell http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:s_flags

Comment: @Paul: By the way, what's is j intended to do? Or it was just a trailing mistake?

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  the j option worked with the vimgrep command, to abort the jump-to-location, so I assumed it'd work in the search too.  My mistake.